# Lock upgradation in Two Phase Locking

Tags: concurrency, databases

Is lock conversion (upgradation) from $Shared$ to $Exclusive$ allowed in

- Basic
- Conservative
- Strict
- Rigorous

types of 2PL techniques.

Following is an example of disallowed attempt of lock conversion for a non serial order of  transactions $T1$ and $T2$:

[image: The transactions]

[image: Example]